# AbstractWizardFormController OR Spring webflow

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

What is the difference in using  AbstractWizardFormController OR Spring  Webflow. How should one decide which one to use in a given scenario.

EDIT:
Is there any benefit of using one over the other?? Does Spring Web Flow provide additional advantages? I am a newbie in Spring and therefore am not very sure of what each of these provides.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AbstractWizardFormController` is deprecated. For that reason alone, I suggest not using it, and either use standard annotated Spring MVC controllers, or using WebFlow. Which you use depends on the complexity of your flow.

Answer (score 1):

The wizard form controller is Spring 1.0 vintage; web flow came afterwards.  I'd say web flow should be preferred, unless your flow is so linear that the simplicity of the wizard is compelling.